# How to use a production bundle stack trace with a map to get the error line

Tags: reactjs, webpack, source-maps

I want to deliver my software with no maps.

Each production build includes its commit hash in order to be able to get the exact code in which the build was made.

I would like to given an error stack trace on prod, and given the commit hash. Checkout to the commit, make a new build but with devtool enabled to generate maps and then, use the stack trace provided to identify where the error happened.

I appreciate any answer as well as the time you use to answer. Thank you

As an alternative, I tryied to make the build with source-maps but it increases the build size a lot. Making it very difficult to be put in production environment because of download times.